# gwt application stopped running suddenly

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

first of all I am sorry on my English.
I have a problem in my Gwt application.
I build Gwt application and I work on application every day
Yesterday I want to still work on my application but is stopped worked and i do not know why and I not get errors
The application compiled and I get the Url to run on browser
I copy the Url to my Firefox browser and not happened nothing.
I put break point in my entry point class and I see the application not arrived to entry point and I do not know why.
I try to open new project to check maybe the problem in eclipse or in Gwt plug in but the new project worked excellent so I understand the problem in specific this project.
I need help 
thank you everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay i have 3 possible suspicions:

1. You updated your Application, but for some reason some JavaScript stayed inside the Firefox cache. Solution: Go to options and "Clean cache" and always try to press CTRL+F5 instead of just reloading, this will clean the current website's cache saved in your Browser.
2. Your HDD is full(less likely). You said you work everyday on the app. The caching in dev-mode is very VERY bad(for me it once contained **300GB** of cached data). there is a folder called <win_user>/AppData/Local/Temp - delete everything inside if you find a lot of "gwt-<something>" files and check the folder's size. There is nothing valuable inside it(if you didn't place anything inside :D)
   P.S. Turns out it was a Firefox Memory-leak that has been fixed in GWT 2.6.0 :)
3. Your Eclipse messed up some random stuff. As always - Project > Clean...

   Then right click on app and let gwt recomile your app(if you have an ant file that uses the gwt-compiler, execute that)

I can't really think of anything else...
The only thing that could be is that YOU changed something, but you said you didn't so...

Hopefully it works,
Laurenz

Comment: Thank you for your help
The first option is the solution