# gwt project not running on browser

Tags: gwt

first of all I am sorry on my English.
I have a problem in my gwt application.
the project not running on browser.
It happened to me once more again, I can not run the project on a browser. It stopped working on the browser and then I decided to install a new browser (chrome). installed chrome and everything was excellent for a couple weeks and then it happened to me also in chrome it stopped working. I tried to delete the Firefox and chrome and reinstall it did not help. I tried all possible helped me in this url:
[gwt application stopped running suddenly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21458991/gwt-application-stopped-running-suddenly)
and it did not help.
In addition the project work well in my friend so no problem in code. 
What else can I do I've staffed Thanks to all helpers
thank you

Comment: Is there any exception/error logged?

Comment: As per your comments its working fine after installing a new browser i.e. there is some issue with browser cache. Clear browser cache before running your application or delete temp data stored under your file system.

Comment: no exception or error in log. I cleared  history in browser but is not helped me I try to remove the browser and reinstall and is no helped me and I deleted all data in file system and is not helped

Comment: Delete gwt-unitCache, generated javascript and WEB-INF/deploy folders. GWT Compile then run the application again.

Comment: no is not helped to me

Comment: Ok I deleted eclipse and reinstall eclipse with gwt plug in and now when I run my project I get this error how I can solve it.  
org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry registerExtensions
WARNING: Extension Point "org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences" not registered, but plugin "" defined in file:c:/location/gwt-dev.jar refers to it.
DataNucleus Enhancer (version 1.1.4) : Enhancement of classes
DataNucleus Enhancer completed with success for 13 classes. Timings : input=190 ms, enhance=44 ms, total=234 ms. Consult the log for full details

Comment: delete c:/location/gwt-dev.jar file. Access it from GWT sdk plugin (com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle). Turn off [DataNucleus Enhancer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015727/how-to-turn-off-datanucleus-enhancer-while-working-with-google-app-engine).

Comment: but is the same location  the full path of gwt plug in is "C:\Users\Gal lavie\Desktop\eclipse\eclipse\plugins\com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.6.0\gwt-2.6.0\gwt-dev.jar" and the full path of error is "C:/Users/Gal%20lavie/Desktop/eclipse/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.6.0/gwt-2.6.0/gwt-dev.jar"

Comment: Turn off DataNucleus Enhancer or Reconfigure GWT SDK in eclipse.

Comment: Click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015727/how-to-turn-off-datanucleus-enhancer-while-working-with-google-app-engine)

Comment: It was a good set src/com/lebsh/floor/server/jdo/

Comment: Ok I noticed the generated folder under var folder not created.
someone know why the folder not created I think this is the problem

Comment: is GWT compilation working fine?

Comment: yes project compiled successfully

Comment: You have to define WAR directory while compiling the project. Try- war argument.

Comment: What do you mean I do not understand

Comment: I not know how but it work now I did reinstall to chrome and suddenly it work. but now I have another problem I get this error in server side. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/core/client/GWTBridge I not know why